# Debug meteorjs application with node-inspector

Tags: debugging, meteor, node-inspector

I am trying to debug a meteor application at server side.

I created an environment variable export NODE_OPTIONS='--debug'.

I run meteor (version 0.7.0.1) command. It tells the debugger listening on port 5858.

I start node-inspector (version v0.7.0-2) and point to 127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858, but I can see only a couple of strings, Source, Console and a prompt > where I cannot write anything.

I have this error in the console:
“The connection to ws//127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/1/websocket/Za… was interrupted while the page was loading”.

The same if I use 0.0.0.0:8080: I can see something more of the debugger on the right panel, as Watch expression, Call stack, but the Source list is still empty.

Node-inspector should be listening, because if I stop meteor says that the remote debugging has been terminated. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/EG8pe7pF3f8

> Just want to share some of my experience on using node-inspector to
>   debug server side codes:
>   1. When you run Meteor, it will spawn two processes on Linux machine
>   (Note: I have not checked this on Windows or Mac machine)
>
> ```
>  process1: /usr/lib/meteor/bin/node /usr/lib/meteor/app/meteor/
> ```
>
> meteor.js
>
> ```
>  process2: /usr/lib/meteor/bin/node /home/paul/codes/bbtest_code/
> ```
>
> bbtest02/.meteor/local/build/main.js --keepalive
>
> 1. You need to send kill -s USR1 on process2
> 2. Run node-inspector and you can see your server code
>
> On my first try, I modify the last line on meteor startup script in /
>   usr/lib/meteor/bin/meteor to
>
> exec "$DEV_BUNDLE/bin/node" $NODE_DEBUG "$METEOR" "$@"
>
> and run NODE_DEBUG=--debug meteor on command prompt. This only put --
>   debug flag on process1 so I only see meteor files on node-inspector
>   and could not find my code.
>   Any suggestion on how to modify the script so we can use "--debug"
>   flag on the meteor script? 
>   Cheers,
>   Paul

Comment: I installed Google Chrome on ubuntu and I now can see the source code and set breakpoints. Unfortunately  the new version of Node Inspector not stopping at break point shttps://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1411. Anyone solved it?