# Server-side debugging for Meteor App on Nitrous.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, nitrousio, node-inspector

I've got a simple Meteor app running on a Nitrous box. I'd like to be able to use `node-inspector` for server-side debugging (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034941/meteor-debug-on-server-side)), but I'm unable to get to the console.

My Meteor app is running locally on the box at `http://0.0.0.0:3000/`, and I can view it in Chrome by following the guide [here](http://help.nitrous.io/preview/). When I then run `node-inspector`, I get this message:

```
Node Inspector v0.8.3
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging.
```

How can I get to this address? I've tried:

- Navigating to `https://example-name.example-region.nitrous.io:8080/debug?port=5858`
- Running: `node-inspector --web-host 0.0.0.0`
- Running: `node-inspector --web-host https://example-name.example-region.nitrous.io`

Thoughts? Is there a way I can get to this console?

Comment: Might this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642993/debug-meteorjs-application-with-node-inspector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change the url on the box,

usually you just run the box running the `meteor` command

```
cd workspace
cd myAPP
meteor
```

and it works, but now you should run this commands.

```
cd workspace
cd myApp
ROOT_URL=http://machinename.abc1-2.nitrousbox.com meteor
```

Now run again `node-inspector`

you should get something like

```
Visit http://machinename.abc1-2.nitrousbox.com:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging.
```